# MySQL pivoting a table while getting the related values

Tags: mysql

I am a very beginner to mysql and sql in general. None of my search results brought the solution I am looking for. I have a database and need to format the output like in the example below. Unfortunately I can't change the database anymore since it's an old project of another employee.

The source table:

```
CustomerID serviceID ratingID employeeID
1          1         A        1
1          2         B        5
1          3         B        2
1          4         A        3

2          1         A        1
2          2         C        5
2          3         D        2
2          4         C        3

3          1         T        1
3          2         O        5
3          3         T        2
3          4         O        3
```

Each Customer has four entries, one for each service. They have set ratings and employees.

The output that I need (employeeID can be ignored):

```
CustomerID ServiceID=1 ServiceID=2 ServiceID=3 ServiceID=4
1          A           B           B           A
2          A           C           D           C
3          T           O           T           O
```

I found solutions with group_concat(if())... in the select statement and grouping by customerID, which only brought the values of "1" in each field and not the related values. I tried tying lose selects together with union or subselects but none gave the result I am looking for. Does anybody have a beginner friendly help?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code - or just rotate your monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sample data you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select CustomerID,
  max(case when serviceID = 1 then ratingID end) `ServiceID=1`,
  max(case when serviceID = 2 then ratingID end) `ServiceID=2`,
  max(case when serviceID = 3 then ratingID end) `ServiceID=3`,
  max(case when serviceID = 4 then ratingID end) `ServiceID=4`
from tablename
group by CustomerID
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3A6PaMHvsRcDmuvPkGfa7M/1).
Results:

```
| CustomerID | ServiceID=1 | ServiceID=2 | ServiceID=3 | ServiceID=4 |
| ---------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1          | A           | B           | B           | A           |
| 2          | A           | C           | D           | C           |
| 3          | T           | O           | T           | O           |
```